# Install OS located in Software Center on remote computer using powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

Trying to use the script below to install OS upgrade located in remote PC's Software Center.

```
Function Remote-OS-Upgrade
{
 
Param
(
 [String][Parameter(Position=1)] $Computername,
 [String][Parameter(Position=2)] $OSName,
 [String][Parameter(Position=3)] $Method
)
 
Begin {
 
$Finder = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CCM_Program -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ComputerName $Computername | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $OSName})
 
$Args = @{PackageID = $Finder.PackageID
ProgramID = $Finder.ProgramID
}
}
 
Process
 
{
 
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ClassName CCM_Program -ComputerName $Computername -MethodName $Method -Arguments $Args
}
 
End {}
 
}
Remote-OS-Upgrade testcomputername "OSD - UPGRADE ALL 20H2" "Install"
```

What I get is:
Invoke-CimMethod: The WinRM client cannot process the request. The method name "Install" is not valid. Tried with/without double quotes and still the same.

Any ideas or anyone has another solution that works?

Comment: The [`CCM_Program` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/clients/sdk/ccm_program-client-wmi-class) defines no `Install` method, hence the error.

Comment: Understood. I saw that it has something like ExecuteProgram, tried that too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `CM_Program` class does not have an `Install` method, but the `CCM_ProgramsManager` class does have an `ExecuteProgram` method. So replacing you current Process block with the following should work.

```
Process
 
{
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ClassName "CCM_ProgramsManager"  -MethodName "ExecuteProgram" -Arguments @{ PackageID = $Finder.PackageID ; ProgramID = $Finder.ProgramID}
}
```